# Getting EndpointNotFoundException and WebException connecting to a webservice from a C# app

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I'm trying to connect to a service hosted in our intranet. However while doing so I'm getting this error:

```
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at http://10.XXX.X.XXX:XXXX/servicename/services/SomeSearch.SomeSearchHttpSoap12Endpoint/ that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
```

The inner exception says:

```
 System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond http://10.XXX.X.XXX:XXXX
```

Here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="SomeSearchSoap11Binding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="SomeSearchSoap12Binding" receiveTimeout="01:10:00">
                    <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16" messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8" >
                        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                    </textMessageEncoding>
                    <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous" realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false" useDefaultWebProxy="true"/>
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://10.XXX.X.XXX:XXXX/servicename/services/SomeSearch.SomeSearchHttpSoap11Endpoint/" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SomeSearchSoap11Binding" contract="SomeService.SomeSearchPortType" name="SomeSearchHttpSoap11Endpoint"/>
            <endpoint address="http://10.XXX.X.XXX:XXXX/servicename/services/SomeSearch.SomeSearchHttpSoap12Endpoint/" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="SomeSearchSoap12Binding" contract="SomeService.SomeSearchPortType" name="SomeSearchHttpSoap12Endpoint"/>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

These are the steps I followed:

- I added a service reference by providing the wsdl path.
- Instantiated the SomeSearchPortTypeClient
- Invoked a method on the client as below:

  var someService= new SomeSearchPortTypeClient("SomeSearchHttpSoap12Endpoint");
  var documents = someService.getSomething("123");

When I do this, I'm getting the above exception.

I also tried the pinging to 10.XXX.XXX.XXXX, which timed out. Could this be a firewall issue? If yes, what should be my next steps? What other angles should I pursue to get this working?

One thing to note is that the proxy client is instantiated without any exceptions, only while making a service call it throws me back this error.

Comment: Can you give us the url of the wsdl that you used when you add the service reference?

Comment: http://INTRANETSITE:PORT/servicename/services/SomeSearch?wsdl

Comment: Does INTRANETSITE:PORT = 10.XXX.X.XXX:XXXX?

Comment: No, it's not.It's something like http://abcd01-any.location.bu.company.com:7001. The 10:XXX is generated into my config file when I add the wsdl.

Comment: Then try replacing 10.XXX with  abcd01-ny.location.bu.company.com:7001

Comment: It worked with what Thomas Li suggested.